# Version Information in Embarcadero C++ Builder at compile time

Tags: c++builder

Is it somehow possible to get the projects version info (major/minor/release/build) at compile time? Something like this?

```
#if MAJOR_VERSION=2
#include <fancyheader.h>
#else
#include <differentCoolStuff.h>
#endif
```

yours
Herwig

Comment: Not that I know of, but the `.cbproj` file (an XML file) has a tag named `VerInfo_Keys` that contains the information in a `;` separated list. In that list you have `FileVersion` and `ProductVersion`. If you really want it, I guess you could add a preprocessing step that extracts that info and defines the macros you need and put them in a `version_info.h` file or similar.

Comment: ... but I recommend versioning the sourcecode by using a version control system of some sort instead of littering the code with traces of old versions.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done. Reading the verson number from the exe file ensures that the version number you read (and probably display or change s/w operation based on it) matches the value that a user sees if they check the exe file version information using the Windows
"properties" check, so it makes a lot of sense. This code works with VCL framework using C++ Builder 10.4 (Enterprise edition - but it should work with any edition).

```
   String ExeFileName = ParamStr(0);
   unsigned long Handle;
   int VersionInfoSize = GetFileVersionInfoSize(ExeFileName.c_str(), &Handle);
   int VersionInfo[4];
   void *FileInfo;
   unsigned int Length;
   //if size is zero, then there is no version info in the exe
   if (VersionInfoSize > 0) {
      char *Buffer = new char[VersionInfoSize];
      try {
         GetFileVersionInfo(ExeFileName.c_str(), 0, VersionInfoSize, Buffer);
         VerQueryValue(Buffer, L"\\", &FileInfo, &Length);
         TVSFixedFileInfo *Info = static_cast<TVSFixedFileInfo *>(FileInfo);
         VersionInfo[0] = ((Info->dwFileVersionMS) >> 16);
         VersionInfo[1] = ((Info->dwFileVersionMS) & 0xffff);
         VersionInfo[2] = ((Info->dwFileVersionLS) >> 16);
         VersionInfo[3] = ((Info->dwFileVersionLS) & 0xffff);

      } catch (...) {
         VersionInfo[0] = 99;
         VersionInfo[1] = 88;
         VersionInfo[2] = 77;
         VersionInfo[3] = 66;
      }
      delete[] Buffer;
      // DO WHAT YOU WANT WITH VersionInfo HERE !!!
   }
```

Comment: Reading the version info from the executable file is well documented and easy. My question was about reading the version at COMPILE TIME, when there is no exe file available...